# Meteor 1.3: can I import from the meteor shell?

Tags: meteor

I have a file like this.

```
const device = new Device({
  host: process.env.GALIL_HOST,
  port parseInt(process.env.GALIL_PORT, 10)
});

export default device;
```

However, I cannot find a way to access this in the shell, other than to expose it as a global variable.

Is there any way to import from the meteor shell?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible to import certain symbols from the shell, depending on your Meteor version.

---

## `require()` - client and server, Meteor v1.3+

As of Meteor v.1.3-beta.12, it is possible to `require` files from the shell.

Given a file in a source directory other than `client` (i.e, something that should be available on the server), with the path

> my/file/path/the_file.js

You can get an object that contains your exports using

```
require('./my/file/path/the_file.js');
```

(note the `./` prefix).

or, for packages:

```
require("meteor/my-package");
```

In the browser, you can `require` files and packages, for example:

```
const { Match, check } = require('meteor/check');
```

---

## `import` statements - server, Meteor v1.3.3+

Starting with Meteor v1.3.3, it is possible to use `import` statements from the Meteor shell on the server:

```
import { Match, check } from 'meteor/check';
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! Do you happen to know whether the same can be done on the client in any way?

Comment: Pretty much the same thing. `require('./client/modules/foo/bar')`.

Comment: Importing modules from packages directory inside meteor shell has been fixed on 1.3.3: [Issue #6271](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6271).

Comment: @AdrianoP, you are correct. I will update the answer to reflect it.