# Meteor access mongo object through client

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Many tutorials and documentations later, I still cannot display data from Mongo in the Meteor client.

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
export const Skills = new Mongo.Collection('skills')

Template.Skills.helpers({
        skills: function() {
        return Skills.find();
        }
    });
```

skills.html

```
<template name="Skills">
<h2>My Skills</h2><ul>
     {{#each skills}}
        {{> SkillItem}}
     {{/each}}   
    </ul>
</template>
```

entering Skills.find(); in the developer console does not really do anything except give me the following error.

Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: Skills is not defined

Comment: Are you defining the `Skills` collection in the same file as your template helpers?

Comment: No, that is the entire file. I have 2 records in mongo.

Comment: Files from app modules are not available in the global scope, so you won't be able to user them directly from the console. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754852/meteor-1-3-can-i-import-from-the-meteor-shell/35762227#35762227) for details about importing symbols from the browser console. Anyway, you will need to publish your documents and subscribe to them in order to have them available on the client. Did you do that?

Comment: even then, I still cannot get anything through Skills.find() i have reinstalled autopublish, so everything should be available on both sides right?

Comment: Did you define the collection on the server?

Comment: do you mean having export const Skills = new Mongo.Collection('skills'); in lib/collections/skills.js?

Comment: If you add it both in the `/lib` directory and the template file, it will be defined twice on the server. Make sure that the collection is defined only once in each environment. I would advise against using `autopublish`, as you don't learn the proper way of transferring data between the server and the client.

Comment: Thanks you pointed me in the right direction. I will post the answer later.